# Ask location to save text file created using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, savefiledialog

i am exporting datagridview data into format of text file,
i tried the below code

```
        string dirLocationString = @"C:\Users\palanar\Desktop\result.txt";
        StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(dirLocationString);
        string lines = "";
        lines = "DateTime" + "\t" + "TestStatus" + "\t" + "BatPackSN" + "\t" + "CellSN"
                + "\t" + "BlockSN" + "\t" + "UI_ID" + "\t" + "UI_ParentID" + "\t" + "OperationNumber"
                + "\t" + "OperationName" + "\t" + "EquipmentNumber" + "\t" + "EquipmentName" + "\t" + "WorkOrder"
                + "\t" + "Assembly" + "\t" + "ProductName" + "\t" + "HandlingDuration" + "\t" + "OperationDuration"
                + "\t" + "RepairID" + "\t" + "DefectID" + "\t" + "UitemLevelCode" + "\t" + "UIEventLevelCode";
        sW.WriteLine(lines);
        for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
        {
            string lines1 = "";
            for (int col = 0; col <= 19; col++)
            {
                lines1 += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines1) ? " " : "\t") + dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
            }

            sW.WriteLine(lines1);
        }
```

here the data is exported perfectly and saved in the format of text file, the problem is here i have assigned default location, instead of this it should ask for the location by opening save dialogue.

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar,  windows desktop application.

Comment: Side note: when working with `IDisposable` wrap it into `using`, in your case `using (StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter ...) {...}`

Comment: also the `vb.net` tag is useless here, it is `c#` only

Comment: @ArchanaPalani - the code in the question is totally unecessary as its not at all related to your problem. Post only the required code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looking for  `saveFileDialog` [this is a tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog)

Example:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

sfd.Filter = "Text file(*.txt)|*.txt";
sfd.FilterIndex = 1;

if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel) { return; }
string dirLocationString = sfd.FileName;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //your selected file location 
            string dirLocationString = sfd.FileName;
        }
```